# log rule when a contant is in the formula

Tags: logarithms

Can we say that $log \;k2^{k-1}$ is the same as $k *log \;2^{k-1}$ ? where $k$ is a constant ?

Comment: When in doubt try plugging in some values of $k$ and check if they are equal.

Comment: I think the log identities you may be confusing are $\log_c a^b=b\log_c a$ and $\log_c ab=\log_c a + \log_c b$

Comment: No, you can't. Unless $k=1$.

Comment: @lulu or $k=2$.

Comment: @projectilemotion  True!